# Pega valores checkbox

Tags: php, html

Preciso pegar mais de um valor de checkbox, caso tenha mais de um valor, exemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="combustivel[]" value="Marco">
<input type="checkbox" name="combustivel[]" value="Empres contratada">
<input type="checkbox" name="combustivel[]" value="Desconto">
```

Caso eu precise marcar o checkbox Marco e Desconto, como posso fazer pra pegar esses dois?

Peguei esse código na web:

```
if(!empty($_POST['combustivel'])) {
  foreach($_POST['combustivel'] as $comb) {
          echo $comb;
  }
}
```

Mas o seguinte aviso surge:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()....

Comment: Seu código parece correto, testei ele com esse [exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fr0-bfg4). `Invalid argument supplied` significa que era esperado um array e veio outra coisa.

Comment: Seu código parece correto mesmo, talvez seja outra coisa. O tipo de requisição realmente é POST, não GET? Pra testar isso, execute um `var_dump($_POST); exit;`  antes deste `foreach` e veja se os valores foram retornados.

Comment: @Perdeu? Você quer dizer que a variável $comb deve ser $comb[], seria isso?

Comment: Veja o retorno de `print_r($_POST['combustivel']);` deve ser um array. Coloque isso antes do if

Comment: Esse erro aparece apenas quando você não seleciona nenhuma opção ou aparece sempre?

Comment: Sempre que fores tentar obter um dado numa array, imprime sempre o resultado com `print_r();` como o @perdeu disse, e para o teu caso, creio que a sentença para o `foreach` deve ser `foreach($_POST['combustivel] as $comb=>$valor){ echo $valor }`.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez este erro esteja acontecendo porque nenhuma opção foi selecionada, tenta utilizar [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-array.php) ao invés de [empty()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php).

```
if (is_array($_POST['combustivel'])) {
    foreach($_POST['combustivel'] as $comb) {
        echo $comb;
    }
}
```